# How to make this HTML code opens in a new tab?

Tags: html

I have this HTML code from AWeber (Sign-Up form) and i put it in my custom form. The problem is, when i put this in my custom form, it doesn't open in a new tab, it opens in the SAME window.
Here's my HTML code:

```
<!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
<style type="text/css">
#af-form-1703374297 .af-body .af-textWrap{width:98%;display:block;float:none;}
#af-form-1703374297 .af-body input.text, #af-form-1703374297 .af-body textarea{background-color:#FFFFFF;border-color:#919191;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
#af-form-1703374297 .af-body input.text:focus, #af-form-1703374297 .af-body textarea:focus{background-color:#FFFAD6;border-color:#030303;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;}
#af-form-1703374297 .af-body label.previewLabel{display:block;float:none;text-align:left;width:auto;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
#af-form-1703374297 .af-body{padding-bottom:15px;padding-top:15px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:inherit;background-image:none;color:#000000;font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
#af-form-1703374297 .af-quirksMode{padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;}
#af-form-1703374297 .af-standards .af-element{padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;}
#af-form-1703374297 .buttonContainer input.submit{background-color:#f2f2f2;background-image:url("https://forms.aweber.com/images/forms/pointer/alert/button.png");color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
#af-form-1703374297 .buttonContainer input.submit{width:auto;}
#af-form-1703374297 .buttonContainer{text-align:center;}
#af-form-1703374297 button,#af-form-1703374297 input,#af-form-1703374297 submit,#af-form-1703374297 textarea,#af-form-1703374297 select,#af-form-1703374297 label,#af-form-1703374297 optgroup,#af-form-1703374297 option{float:none;position:static;margin:0;}
#af-form-1703374297 div{margin:0;}
#af-form-1703374297 form,#af-form-1703374297 textarea,.af-form-wrapper,.af-form-close-button,#af-form-1703374297 img{float:none;color:inherit;position:static;background-color:none;border:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
#af-form-1703374297 input,#af-form-1703374297 button,#af-form-1703374297 textarea,#af-form-1703374297 select{font-size:100%;}
#af-form-1703374297 select,#af-form-1703374297 label,#af-form-1703374297 optgroup,#af-form-1703374297 option{padding:0;}
#af-form-1703374297,#af-form-1703374297 .quirksMode{width:100%;max-width:462.4px;}
#af-form-1703374297.af-quirksMode{overflow-x:hidden;}
#af-form-1703374297{background-color:#FFFFFF;border-color:transparent;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;}
#af-form-1703374297{display:block;}
#af-form-1703374297{overflow:hidden;}
.af-body .af-textWrap{text-align:left;}
.af-body input.image{border:none!important;}
.af-body input.submit,.af-body input.image,.af-form .af-element input.button{float:none!important;}
.af-body input.text{width:100%;float:none;padding:2px!important;}
.af-body.af-standards input.submit{padding:4px 12px;}
.af-clear{clear:both;}
.af-element label{text-align:left;display:block;float:left;}
.af-element{padding:5px 0;}
.af-form-wrapper{text-indent:0;}
.af-form{text-align:left;margin:auto;}
.af-quirksMode .af-element{padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important;}
.lbl-right .af-element label{text-align:right;}
body {
}
</style>
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" target="_new" >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1703374297" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlist4016661" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.gainthemuscle.com/5-tips-to-get-ripped-fast/" id="redirect_96cab6cdb292c6e977bd8df9f5c83350" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="Muscle-Building" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<div id="af-form-1703374297" class="af-form"><div id="af-body-1703374297" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-76911094"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-76911094" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="500" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " />
</div><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer">
<input name="submit" id="af-submit-image-1703374297" type="image" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" alt="Submit Form" src="https://forms.aweber.com/images/forms/pointer/alert/button.png" tabindex="501" />
<div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=jOwMzMzsLEyc7A==" alt="" /></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    (function() {
        var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
        if (!IE) { return; }
        if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {
            if (document.getElementById("af-form-1703374297")) {
                document.getElementById("af-form-1703374297").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-body-1703374297")) {
                document.getElementById("af-body-1703374297").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-header-1703374297")) {
                document.getElementById("af-header-1703374297").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-footer-1703374297")) {
                document.getElementById("af-footer-1703374297").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";
            }
        }
    })();
    -->
</script>
<!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 --
```

>

Comment: Are you sure [all this code is necessary to reproduce your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The question does not make sense, sorry. The markup code in a page itself can _never_ decide or change in what window / tab it is loaded. Only the logic loading the code can, and even that can be overridden by the clients (users) local configuration.

Comment: I noticed something. When i check the form after putting the HTML code by inspect element, the " target="_blank" " part isn't there. The whole code is there except for that part. WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your current form opening tag with the following:

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" target="_blank" >
```

I just changed target="_new" to target="_blank" as target="_new" is invalid and browsers will probably not know how to act on that.